# Как сделать полупрозрачный Google Map

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps-api, google-maps

Вот страница с картой
http://denispostolenko.com/test/contacts.html
Карта сейчас в стандартном стиле. Как сделать ее такой как на картинке?
 Думаю она должна быть прозрачной немного или должна быть полупрозрачная подложка

[image: Google Map]

Comment: opacity а вообще можно код

Comment: в массив styles к каждому элементу приписывать " opacity: .8 "  ?

Comment: да нет просто к iframeу добавить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте этот стиль добавить в конец файла `/test/style.css`

```
.gm-style > div > div {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```

Comment: а будут ли элементы гугл карт после этого кликабельны?

Comment: @kizoso, будут, правда здесь и на маркер фон наложится и он никуда не исчезнет, вообще здесь лучше на js это делать

Comment: С маркером так                                                                                            
.gm-style > div > div {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.5) !important;
}

.gmnoprint {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете полностью заменить цветовую гамму карты по вашему желанию. Можете воспользоваться любым конструктором стилей ([например вот этим](https://snazzymaps.com/editor)) для гугл карт или выбрать из готовых примеров подобное.

Вот пример стилевого решения с приглушенными цветами:

```
[
    {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "stylers": [
            {
                "saturation": -70
            },
            {
                "lightness": 37
            },
            {
                "gamma": 1.15
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "gamma": 0.26
            },
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "lightness": 0
            },
            {
                "saturation": 0
            },
            {
                "hue": "#ffffff"
            },
            {
                "gamma": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.arterial",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "lightness": 20
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "lightness": 50
            },
            {
                "saturation": 0
            },
            {
                "hue": "#ffffff"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "administrative.province",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            },
            {
                "lightness": -50
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "administrative.province",
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "administrative.province",
        "elementType": "labels.text",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "lightness": 20
            }
        ]
    }
]
```